# Oracle sequence not increment properly in hibernate application

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I have requirement where application is connected with schema (Say A ) and Schema A is having permission to access table of another schema (Say B) . When I am trying to insert record through application in clustering environment in Schema B  then sequence is not working properly. it is having increment with One defined in sequence but sometime it will generate high value in second or third insertion  and sometime it will generate less value in 5th or 6th time insertion.

But when I have alter sequence and given NO Cache option then working fine. But this solution is giving me overhead problem .

Comment: you should post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how sequences work. Each time you access cached sequence, the session will get n numbers from the sequence and they can be used anytime until the session is closed. There's no way to control the insertion order.

This is the case for any system that connects with multiple sessions (connection pooling, clustered environment, multiple thick clients connected to same database).

Let's assume following sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq
      INCREMENT BY 1
      START WITH 1
      NOMAXVALUE
      NOCYCLE
      CACHE 10;
```

Session 1 calls test_seq.nextval and receives numbers 1 through 10

Session 2 calls test.seq.nextval and receives numbers 11 through 20

Session 1 inserts three records

Session 2 inserts two records

Session 1 inserts one record

The resulting insertion order will be

```
1
2
3
11
12
4
```

If you need the record id to match the insertion order you can use identity column since Oracle 12c
In general it's better not to assign any special meaning to your primary key column and you're better off keeping track of insertion order via timestamp column.